# rad menu , check if item text exists

Tags: vb.net, telerik, radmenu

Using telerik and the radmenu, do you know how to check if the item exists by text

my menu contains the text "menu1"

If I use  `menu.FindItemByText("menu1").Enabled = False` this will disable the button

BUT

If I use  `menu.FindItemByText("menuTEST").Enabled = False`  then I get an exception  as this button does not exist.

How do I stop the error?

I tried this below but it say it cant return booloen

```
If menu.FindItemByText("menuTEST") then

'do this

End If
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
If Not(menu.FindItemByText("menuTEST") Is Nothing) then

    'do this

End If
```